# How to replace the color of dialog's text buttons?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I'm using a custom theme for my app. When the dark mode is applied, some colors don't match the dark background at all.
For example, text buttons for dialogs:

[image]

According [to the Material documentation](https://material.io/components/dialogs#theming), the text buttons use the Primary color.
But I've noticed that the default theme (the purple, blue-green one) uses some secondary color for the text buttons, which is what I'd like to achieve.

That dialog is popped up by a list preference, so I can't create a custom activity as dialog to replace it with its own style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample theme of custom themed Dialog hope it helps you

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
</style>

//here is importance part
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorSurface</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App.Title.Text</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent</item>
</style>

// for title color
<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App.Title.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_dialog_buttons</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
</style>

// for button colors
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_dialog_buttons</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.MediumComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How do you know which style name affects which UI part ? How do know how to get through the levels until you reach the button style definition ? Is there some sort of editor to clearly see how that stuff actually work ?

Comment: @BogeyJammer as you can see this is the theme XML and it will affect the Ui part witch you declare in the parent part
I leave a comment on the important part for you in code
 when you add the item attributes to the  parent ="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog"  you can customize each part of your dialog with related item

Comment: I actually managed to change that button color thanks to this code. I just wanted to know the process that leaded you achieve it. Is it just like me by copying somebody's work, have you found specific documentation, or is it the result of try and error ?

Comment: @BogeyJammer I'm happy that my code helps you 
I just read the theming doc of material design and play around with it here is the link: https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#theming-dialogs